# How to show diff of a staged deleted file?

Tags: git

Here is the status:

```
On branch howard
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/howard'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    thing.scala
    (and other changed files)
```

If I do `git diff --cached`, it shows the content of `thing.scala` as well as other diffs.

But I am interested to see only the deleted file's content. How to do so in git?

The following attempts don't work:

```
git show HEAD~1 thing.scala
git diff --cached thing.scala
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your first approach is almost right, it just has two small problems.

Firstly, since you haven't committed yet, the last version that still has the `thing.scala` file is `HEAD`. `HEAD~1` is the version before that.

Secondly, the syntax to show a file from a specific commit is `git show <commit>:<file>`.

So the correct command is:

```
git show HEAD:thing.scala
```

The documentation mentions this syntax in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> *<rev>:<path>, e.g. HEAD:README, :README, master:./README*
>
> A suffix *:* followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon. *:path* (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case of the syntax described next: content recorded in the index at the given path. A path starting with *./* or *../* is relative to the current working directory. The given path will be converted to be relative to the working tree’s root directory. This is most useful to address a blob or tree from a commit or tree that has the same tree structure as the working tree.

As for `git diff --cached`: the arguments that follow are interpreted as file names only if they exist as files. Since you removed the file, that doesn't apply. You can force arguments to be interpreted as file names by using `--`:

```
git diff --cached -- thing.scala
```

Comment: Having the incorrect syntax quoted at the beginning of the answer makes it harder to quickly get the needed info, consider removing that or putting the correct command of up top.  Thank you for this quality answer!

Comment: @GrantHumphries The author's account has been deleted, so improving the question is up to the rest of us. I've just made a small edit that in my opinion makes it clearer. Can you tell me what you think?

Comment: I think that many people will fall into the trap, wonder, read again, understand and do the correct thing (like I just did). I think it's a good lesson :-)

Comment: I've just deleted the incorrect command completely, it can be found in the question anyway.